# How do i assign key / value pairs of an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value

```
let arr = ['drink', 'soda', 'name', 'john', 'someKey', 'someValue']
```

I'd like to assign key value pairs of the strings i have in the array above

for example:

```
[{drink: 'soda'},
 {name: 'john'},
 {someKey:'someValue'}
]
```

I've spent hours trying to figure this out... I've tried approaching it with the map method but my limited knowledge on javascript is consistently returning errors...

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out. Thanks

Comment: It may be easiest to just use a "old-fashioned" for-loop and increment your iterator by 2 each time.

Comment: Do you really want `[{drink: 'soda'}, {name: 'john'}, {someKey:'someValue'}]` as three separate objects in an array or do you want a single object with all those properties like `{ drink: 'soda', name: 'john', someKey: 'someValue' }`?

Comment: @Wyck as three seperate objects in an array.@sonEtLumiere gave the solution i needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a simple for loop:

```js
let arr = ['drink', 'soda', 'name', 'john', 'someKey', 'someValue'];

let result = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2) {
  let obj = {}
  obj[arr[i]] = arr[i+1];
  result.push(obj)
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: is there a way to achieve this using the map method?

Comment: While `map`'s callback does have an index argument you can't increase it like you can with this kind of loop which will prevent you from getting the result you want. @moon

Comment: oh right since i'll have to increment i by 2. Thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

A [simple old-school loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) increasing the step by 2 on each iteration.

Note: this will give you a single object with key/value pairs which makes (to my mind) a more useful data structure than an array of objects with one key/value pair each. If you're looking for an array of objects @sonEtLumiere's answer is the right one.

```js
const arr = ['drink', 'soda', 'name', 'john', 'someKey', 'someValue'];

// Initialise empty object
const out = {};

// Loop over the array in steps of 2 so
// that we can access `i` (the key) and 
// `i + 1` (the value) on each iteration
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  out[arr[i]] = arr[i + 1];
}

console.log(out);
console.log(out.drink);
console.log(out.name);
console.log(out.someKey);
```

Comment: Doesn't quite match the expected output provided in the question.

Comment: @Wyck hence all my comments.

Answer (score 1):

That would be the easiest way:

```js
const arr = ['drink', 'soda', 'name', 'john', 'someKey', 'someValue']

const obj = {}
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  obj[arr[i]] = arr[i + 1]
}

console.log(obj)
```

Or if you really want a oneliner

```js
const arr = ['drink', 'soda', 'name', 'john', 'someKey', 'someValue']
const result = arr.reduce((fin, str, i, arr) => i & 1 ? fin : { ...fin, [str]: arr[i + 1] }, {})
console.log(result)
```